# Does LZ4 allow decompressing from the middle of the compressed data?

Tags: c, compression, lz4

I am currently trying to compress/decompress a list of 64-bit integers using [LZ4 algorithm](https://github.com/lz4/lz4).

[In the repository](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/lib/lz4.h#L273), it says that `LZ4_decompress_safe_partial()` can be used to decompress an LZ4 compressed block of desired output bytes, starting at desired position.

Specifically, what I want to do is **to only decompress particular portions of the compressed data, and retrieve only those portions of the given source**.

For instance, in the example of [simple_buffer.c](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/examples/simple_buffer.c), `const char* const src` is given as `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor site amat."`.

After compressing it into `char* compressed_data`, I only want to retrieve, say, `consectetur adipiscing elit` as the output of the decompression, by only partially decompressing `compressed_data`.

[It](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/lib/lz4.h#L274) says that the first argument of `LZ4_decompress_safe_partial()` indicates where to start the decompression. How do I determine the starting position of the `compressed_data` which relates to `c` of `consectetur`? Is there any meta-data or other way to figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't tag multiple different programming languages. If your question is truly language-agnostic there's a tag for that. Otherwise only tag the language you're actually working with.

Comment: Imagine that you have the compressed version of a book with many chapters, and you know A) the starting position of each chapter in the uncompressed data, and B) the compression was careful to make each chapter independently decodable. Then you could request a specific chapter, and the decompressor could quickly skip ahead to the right starting point.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've modified the tag according to your advice.

Comment: @user3386109 I get your point. So do you know if that mechanism also works for LZ4 algorithm? It would be even better if someone can inform me of how to implement it using LZ4 API.

Comment: Where does it say what you claim it says about `src`? | `src` needs to point to beginning of the block. The only difference is that the function may stop decoding before it reaches the end of the full block. Hence "This can be useful to boost performance whenever only the beginning of a block is required."

Comment: As for why -- the decoder needs to see the already decoded output in order to be able to decode length-distance pairs. Say you only started decoding 100 bytes in, and the decoder saw "copy 10 bytes from 50 bytes ago" -- where is it going to get the data to copy?

Comment: How big are the files you want to partially decompress? Given how fast LZ4 is, it's probably not worth doing anything special if it's less than a MiB or so. For bigger files, use multiple smaller blocks (e.g. 64 KiB). Since each block is independent, you can then begin decoding further into the file, at block granularity. Might want to have a look at `lz4frame` (in the same repo) for some inspiration.

Comment: @DanMašek I think I've over-interpreted the explanation on `src`. It indeed seems that `src` needs to point to beginning of the block. I'm aware of LZ4's fast decompression. Despite that, I have to partially decompress since the file that I want to decompress is extremely large (let's say it takes up to 70% of the RAM size). Therefore, what I want to do is, decompress only parts that are currently demanded, discard away after use, then decompress another part that are newly needed, and so on.

Comment: @DanMašek I'm not familiar with concept of blocks that you mentioned. I will take a look at the `lz4frame` document and other documents related to block granularity. Thanks for your advice.